# For Graph API, what are the permissions req'd for creating a post on a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For Graph API, what are the permissions req'd for creating a post on a facebook page?

Call

```
curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{PageId}/feed \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"message": "Test", "link": "https://example.com", "published": true, "access_token":{AccessToken}}'
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200
    }
}
```

Over in the App dashboard permissions

- I'm the admin
- The access required for page_read_engagment & pages_manage_posts is "Standard access"
- The system is logging that these requests are being seen ([image: see attached])

Also note, the App is live.

What additional permissions or what else might be keeping this API call from processing?

Comment: Your screenshot shows what permissions your app _can_ ask for, but that doesn't necessarily mean, your currently used access token encompasses them. Debug your token, and see which permissions it actually contains as granted.

Answer (score 0):

> For a person who can perform tasks on the page, you will need to
> implement Facebook Login to ask for the following permissions and
> receive a Page access token:

```
 pages_manage_engagement
 pages_manage_posts
 pages_read_engagement
 pages_read_user_engagement
 publish_video permission, if you are publishing a video to the Page
```

> Your app user must be able to perform the CREATE_CONTENT, MANAGE, and
> MODERATE tasks on the Page in the API requests.

Information source : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/posts/

Comment: Also the error seems like you're mistakenly entering a group Id, instead of Page ID.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd actually checked all those specs, and they're all permitted under "Standard access", so I'm wondering if there's some more hidden requirement for additional permissions.  For instance, does "business verification" conceivably add permissions not formally described on the pages you cited?

Comment: Yes, some of the endpoints are only access after getting additional permissions. Facebook keeps addition such things to avoid spam.